# Is IBM Maximo 7.6 businessobject jar compiled in Java 1.8 compatible to run in java 1.7?

Tags: maximo

I have got jar compiled in java 1.8 from maximo dir and on my machine i have java 1.7 installed do i need to update my machine java before i run this jar. I can not run it before knowing this since it will get recorded in some logs and will update some server side files.

Answer (score 0):

This is more of a Java question than a Maximo question, but no, it will not. You will get an "Unsupported major.minor version 52.0" if you do. This is not because of any features issue, this is simply because the bytecode is tagged as being from Java 8 and so earlier JREs will not run it.

Now this assumes you actually compiled the class files using Java 8, which probably only happened if you have custom code in there. If you are just using the out-of-the-box Maximo classes, those came pre-compiled (in I don't recall which version of Java) and so all you might have done was to bundle them into a jar, or more likely into the Maximo ear (since you don't run the businessobjects.jar). In that case, it doesn't matter what version of Java you used to created the jar/ear, it will run on any version of Java that is the same as or higher than whatever version IBM used to compile the code into classes.